# My Curious Music Box

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, word-property

I have an exceptional music box. I can put words inside it. But not all. Here are some of what this curious box admits:

- Relation
- Abomination
- Sofa
- Umbrella
- Antidote
- Gasoline
- Desire

**Can you deduce which words my box admits?**

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your box likes

> words that contain tonic sol-fa syllables.

Thus:

> **relati**on
>  abo**mi**na**ti**on
>  **sofa**
>  umb**re**l**la**
>  an**tidote**
>  ga**so**line (I think you could also count "li", as a sharpened "la")
>  de**sire**

Comment: Congrats! Pretty fast too!

Comment: How in the world did you think of that so quickly??? Humans are only supposed to have *one* brain, y'know! ;)

Answer (score 5):

This has already been answered but I found another answer that fits all the provided words.

---

Your box admits

> Words that contain other words inside them

So we get

> R[**elation**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/elation#English)
>  Abomi**nation**
>  **So**fa (or S**of**a)
>  [**Umbre**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/umbre#English)lla
>  Anti[**dote**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dote#English)
>  Gaso**line**
>  De**sire**

Comment: I believe the syllables found in the other answer are also words, so that answer is strictly more precise.

Comment: @noedne, leaving apart the accuracy, the other answer is the correct one simply because the title of the post. **Music** here is the important clue of this riddle.